# NetSuite SuiteScript 1.0: Cannot save quote in RESTlet

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript1.0

So I'm trying to create an estimate (quote) within NetSuite using SuiteScript 1.0.

I have been following this example provided from NetSuite's help centre:

**Example 1
The following example creates an estimate with two items.**

```
var record = nlapiCreateRecord('estimate');
record.setFieldValue('entity', 79);
record.setFieldValue('memo', 'Estimate Memo' );
record.setLineItemValue('item', 'item', 1, 21);
record.setLineItemValue('item', 'quantity', 1, 10 );
record.setLineItemValue('item', 'price', 1, 1 );
record.setLineItemValue('item', 'item', 2, 21);
record.setLineItemValue('item', 'quantity', 2, 5 );
record.setLineItemValue('item', 'price', 2, 2 );
var id = nlapiSubmitRecord(record, true);
```

The problem I get however is on that last line, whenever I go to try and save the record:

`nlapiSubmitRecord(record, true);`

I get the following error:

`Module does not exist: ../Client/OFI_ActionButtonsClient.js (SYSTEM_LIBS$debugger.sys#475)`

Has anyone else come across this? And know what could be causing the issue? Just for reference I am just running this script through the inbuilt script debugger in NetSuite.

Please note as well, I have tried writing this up using SuiteScript 2.0, and my issue then was that only custom fields were being saved, whereas the primary/ inbuilt fields for the quote in NetSuite had no values added at all.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the entire code. Are you using any library scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're trying to use a relative path to access a dependency library while running on the debugger

../Client/OFI_ActionButtonsClient.js

Use the full path instead

/SuiteScripts/{your path}/Client/OFI_ActionButtonsClient.js

Comment: Hi Felipe, sorry I was just wondering if you might how do you add in a dependency to a version 1.0 script? There's so many resources out there for 2.0, so I'm probably typing the wrong things in to search, but if you're able to advise that would be a massive help! Thank you

Comment: In the NS Scripts page you need to link the library files, and then you'll have access to those methods. There is no way to add them programatically.

Comment: Oh my goodness thank you!! So it's in the libraries sublist under the 1.0 scripts? In that case, I'm guessing there's no way to test it in the debugger either, you would just have to upload it and call the script through something like Postman to see that it goes through?

Comment: Actually, weirdly enough, when I include that line to set the customform value in the script, it works *IF* I don't add in the dependency to the script.. otherwise it fails when I try to explicitly do so with some strange/ new error (something like: ReferenceError: "define" is not defined. (OFI_ActionButtonsClient.js#4)). I'm not really sure why it works that way.. but at least it's all up and running, and I can set that field with no issues now!

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to fix the issue. The problem was with me trying to set the customform field. So removing this line in my own code helped fix the issue, and I was able to successfully save the record:

```
record.setFieldValue('customform', '123' );
```

Initially I thought it was a problem with the save, but it seems like it was actually happening much earlier on, and only just manifested itself at the point of saving. I'm not entirely sure *why* that was the case, but for anyone else who might be stuck on this I thought it might be useful to know.

Thanks all.